# Displaying specific image and MySql information when clicked on

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am building an image uploading website. Images are uploaded to a directory on the server and data such as the filename is stored in a MySql table. I have created a 'gallery' page which displays all the uploaded images as thumbnails. When a user clicks on one of the images, it takes them to 'image.php' page, which will display the image full size and echo information such as the username of the person who uploaded the image etc.

I am unsure as to what would be the correct way of displaying the image. The images in my MySql table have unique ID's which I'm guessing will have to be manipulated in some way, but how do I would I get the ID of the photo that has been clicked on into the 'image.php' MySql query?

Hope this has been explained well enough. Thanks in advance.

gallery.php page... (exclusing database connections etc.)

```
    //Retrieves data from MySQL 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 {
 ?> 

<section class="thumbnails group">

<a href="image.php?id=<?php $info['id'] ?>"> <?php Echo "<img src=http://.../thumbs/tn_".$info['filename'] .">"; }?> </a>

</section>
```

image.php page...

```
//Retrieves data from MySQL 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE 'id' = ??");
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 {
 ?> 

<section class="main-image group">

<?php echo "<img src=http://.../images/".$info['filename'] .">"; }?>

</section>
```

Comment: How are you storing and referencing your images?

Comment: My images are currently being referenced on the gallery page by a mysql query. $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
I then echo this in a loop until all thumbnails are displayed.
<a href="image.php">
<?php Echo "<img src=http://...thumbs/tn_".$info['filename'] .">"; }?>
</a>

Comment: I mean are the images stored in the file system or on the DB

Comment: Images are stored in the file system, filenames are stored in the DB.

Comment: then liquorvicar is correct...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass the ID of the image through in the querystring

```
<a href="image.php?image=' . $imageID . '"><img src="/path/to/thumbnail"></a>
```

In your image.php page, you can retrieve the ID like this (assuming it's an integer):

```
$imageID = intval( $_GET["image"]);
```

You should then be able to retrieve the path to the image and display it.

Comment: What would the $imageID variable look like? I have this but how would I get the selected ID into the query? $imageID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE 'id' = ???");

Comment: whta is your skill level with PHP? You should have assigned the image to a page using it's id, well possibly retrieved it in the mysql query, this is the id that you will pass. Are you asking how to retrieve the id on the other page from the query string??

Comment: I am a novice, and usually I would take the time to learn the basics before attempting such a thing but the scheduling of university deadlines means I have to 'run' before I can walk, hence why I am struggling. The image that is uploaded has an id which is stored in the MySql DB under the name 'id', which all works. So on the image.php page I need to get the id of the image that has been clicked on in order to display the full size image and other information stored in the DB.

Comment: @user1134548 I've edited my answer to suggest how you might retrieve the id of the image in the image.php script.

Answer (score 0):

@ liquorvicar answer is correct one, there's no ambiguity in his answer! well,

try this;

`<a href="image.php?id=<?php $info['image_id'] ?>"> <?php Echo "<img src=http://...thumbs/tn_".$info['filename'] .">"; }?> </a>`

on image.php page

`$id=intval($_REQUEST['id'])`

now you have id for that specific image show its related info.